# Jquery and Google Maps in Wordpress not showing up

Tags: jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I'm working with a theme for wordpress and for some reason the map will not show up.  I'm not sure what's happening.

I'm also getting a 602 error when i'm double clicking on it in the backend.  But doesn't seem to be erros here.

Thanks so much in advance for any help

Comment: You will probably want to show us what you have done so far as this is a pretty broad an non-specific question.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

602 errors indicate the location you requested could not be found.  can you verify the location is accurate?